# Improve performance in LINQ To Entities query (aggregation)

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this EF model:

```
class Reception
{
     public string Code { get; set; }
     public virtual List<Row> { get; set; }
}

class Row 
{
     public string Item { get; set; }
     public int Quantity { get; set; }
     public float Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to improve the following LINQ To Entities query?

```
dbContext.Receptions.Select(r => new 
{
     code = r.Code,
     quantitySum = r.Rows.Sum(e => e.Quantity),
     weightSum = r.Rows.Sum(e => e.Weight),
});
```

I'm worried about doing twice the "`r.Rows`" part.

Should I not be worried?

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate queries (and especially these containing multiple aggregates) are better translated to SQL if based on `GroupBy`, because that's the natural SQL construct for aggregates.

So if you want better translation and suffer the code readability, the query in question can be turned into `left outer join` + `group by` like this:

```
var query = dbContext.Receptions
    .SelectMany(r => r.Rows.DefaultIfEmpty(), (r, e) => new
    {
        r.Code,
        Quantity = (int?)e.Quantity ?? 0,
        Weight = (float?)e.Weight ?? 0,
    })
    .GroupBy(e => e.Code, (key, g) => new
    {
        code = key,
        quantitySum = g.Sum(e => e.Quantity),
        weightSum = g.Sum(e => e.Weight),
    });
```

which translates to something like this

```sql
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Code], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2], 
     CAST( [GroupBy1].[A2] AS real) AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Join1].[K1] AS [K1], 
        SUM([Join1].[A1]) AS [A1], 
        SUM([Join1].[A2]) AS [A2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[Code] AS [K1], 
            CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Quantity] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent2].[Quantity] END AS [A1], 
            CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Weight] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as real) ELSE [Extent2].[Weight] END AS [A2]
            FROM  [dbo].[Receptions] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Rows] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Code] = [Extent2].[Reception_Code]
        )  AS [Join1]
        GROUP BY [K1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

which is the best you can get from EF6 for this particular query.

Comment: Damn... performance vs code readability. I will need to think about it

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Normally, EF should convert this to a fairly efficient DB query, using SUM functions on the DB side as well. But if you want to be sure, use your SQL Server Profiler to analyze the query.

I ran this code quickly for you and this is what EF does:

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project2].[Code] AS [Code], 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
     CAST( [Project2].[C2] AS real) AS [C2]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project1].[Code] AS [Code], 
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        (SELECT SUM([Extent3].[Weight]) AS [A1] FROM [dbo].[Rows] AS [Extent3] WHERE [Project1].[Id] = [Extent3].[Reception_Id]) AS [C2]
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
            (SELECT SUM([Extent2].[Quantity]) AS [A1] FROM [dbo].[Rows] AS [Extent2] WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Reception_Id]) AS [C1]
        FROM 
            [dbo].[Receptions] AS [Extent1]
        )AS [Project1]
    )AS [Project2]
```

Surely, we can write a better query, with less subselects, but in reality, this query is not something SQL server will trip over.

Comment: This shows the double select from `dbo.Rows` and in my experience *is* something SQL Server does not optimise as well as a single select from that table.

Comment: This query has the exact same execution plan: SELECT 
    [Id], 
    [Code], 
 (SELECT SUM([Extent2].[Quantity]) AS [A1] FROM [dbo].[Rows] AS [Extent2] WHERE re.[Id] = [Extent2].[Reception_Id]) AS [C1],
    (SELECT SUM([Extent3].[Weight]) AS [A1] FROM [dbo].[Rows] AS [Extent3] WHERE re.[Id] = [Extent3].[Reception_Id]) AS [C2]
FROM 
 [dbo].[Receptions] re

Comment: But with a join and a group by, you can still win a bit.